# Check for duplicate key name instances in php array

Tags: php

How would I best go about finding duplicate key names in an array in PHP?
I'm trying to validate a POST array, and realized that I need to make sure that there aren't any duplicate key names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a PHP array, the key is what identifies an element -- so, there can be no duplicate key.

Comment: Here I am :-) Haven't been arround for a couple of months ; been back a few weeks ; not sure how long I'll stay -- but, right now, I'm here ;-)

Comment: Well, it's good to know that you still have an Internet, a computer, a browser, and a brain! :)

Comment: Thanks ^^ What I don't have enough, actually, is not internet/computer/browser -- it is time :-(

Comment: Alright, thanks, rethought the validation, so it's no longer a problem :)

Answer (score 2):

there can't be duplicate keys (only duplicate values).

The second added value to an array with the same key will overwrite the first.